# On clearing input label I'm getting a component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have designed the following component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Search(props) {
  const [studentData, setStudentData] = useState({
    studentName: "",
    joiningDate: "",
  });

  const onAdd = () => {
    
        const emptyObject = {
          name: "",
          joiningDate: "",
        };
        setStudentData(emptyObject);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="my-50 layout-row align-items-end justify-content-end">
      <label htmlFor="studentName">
        Student Name:
        <div>
          <input
            id="studentName"
            name="studentName"
            data-testid="studentName"
            type="text"
            value={studentData.name}
            onChange={onRecordUpdate}
            className="mr-30 mt-10"
          />
        </div>
      </label>
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

[image]
Issue is that when I try to clear the input fields after entering them in the Residents List using following code in the function "Search"

```
const emptyObject = {
  name: "",
  joiningDate: "",
};
setStudentData(emptyObject);
```

I get the following error. I'm not sure why React is assuming the input label to be uncontrolled as I'm initializing it using state.

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
    in input (at Search.js:88)
    in div (at Search.js:87)
    in label (at Search.js:85)
    in div (at Search.js:84)
    in Search (at App.js:35)
    in div (at App.js:34)
    in div (at App.js:32)
    in App (at src/index.js:8)
```

Can anybody provide any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're using `studentName` in the initial state and as value for the input and inside `emptyObject` just `name`. So `studentName` will be `undefined` and React assumes the uncontrolled component.

I think renaming `name` to `studentName` will fix your problem.

Comment: This indeed fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashar Glad to hear that. Feel free to upvote or mark my answer :-)